# Python get length of printed string

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have the args and kwargs of a print funtion, is there any way to get the length of the printed string?

e.g.

```
>>> args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> kwargs = {'sep':'<='}
>>> print (*args, **kwargs)
1<=2<=3<=4
>>> printlen (*args, **kwargs)
11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using StringIO and capture standard output as string.

```
from io import StringIO 
import sys
old_out = sys.stdout # Store stdout to a temp
result = StringIO() # Will capture standard output as string
sys.stdout = result # assign result to sys.stdout
args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
kwargs = {'sep':'<='}
print (*args, **kwargs) # This will be written to result, Not displayed in stdout
sys.stdout = old_out # restore stdout to make things normal
res = result.getvalue()
print ("result: {}, length: {}".format(res, len(res)))
```

Note that everything that is sent to standard output will be captured in result variable till you restore stdout.